# How to fetch specific data from the collection using mongo query using asp.net core

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core

How to fetch specific data from the collection using mongo query using asp.net core.

```
            var Client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
            var dbName = Client.GetDatabase(databaseName);
            var collection = dbName.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName);
            var res = collection.Find({},{_id:0,name:1}).ToList();
```

The error is:

> String contains extra non-whitespace characters beyond the end of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
var res = collection.Find({},{_id:0,name:1}).ToList();
```

to

```
var res = collection.find({},{_id:0,name:1}).ToList();
```

Use **find** rather than Find.

Comment: Using find instead of Find the error is
'IMongoCollection<BsonDocument>' does not contain a definition for 'find' and no accessible extension method 'find' accepting a first argument of type 'IMongoCollection<BsonDocument>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)